# How to execute users input from info from mysql database using python

Tags: python

```
def choice_2():
    number = int(input("Enter year:   "))
    if not conn:
        connect()      

    query = "SELECT * from country IndepYear"    
    with conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, (number))

        country = cursor.fetchall()

        print()
```

in anaconda app giving me an error, Why?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

**In this solution to your problem is putting your input in brackets (  ,) so the result would look something like this:**

```
user_input = (raw_input("Enter year:"), )
```

**Don't forget to put the comma ,**

**In full you have**

```
import MySQLdb
servername = "localhost";
username = "username";
password = "password";
conn = MySQLdb.connect(user=username,host=servername, passwd=password, db=db)
cursor = conn.cursor()
user_input = (raw_input("Enter year:"), )
query= ("SELECT * from country IndepYear")
cursor.execute(query,user_input)
```

Comment: def choice_2():
    user_input = (input("Enter year:  "), )
    
    
    if not conn:
        connect()      
        
    query = "SELECT * from country IndepYear"    
    with conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, user_input)
        
        country = cursor.fetchall()
        print()

Comment: please help me,

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked after couple time tries